# No O(1) operation to join elements from two forward_lists?

Tags: c++, complexity-theory, c++11

When reading about `forward_list` in the FCD of C++11 and [N2543](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2543.htm) I stumbled over one specific overload of `splice_after` (slightly simplified and let `cit` be `const_iterator`):

```
void splice_after(cit pos, forward_list<T>& x, cit first, cit last);
```

The behavior is that after `pos` everything between `(first,last)` is moved to `this`. Thus:

```
  this: 1 2 3 4 5 6           x: 11 12 13 14 15 16
          ^pos                      ^first   ^last
will become:
  this: 1 2 13 14 3 4 5 6     x: 11 12       15 16
          ^pos                      ^first   ^last
```

The description includes the complexity:

> Complexity: O(distance(first, last))

I can see that this is because one needs to adjust `PREDECESSOR(last).next = pos.next`, and the `forward_list` does not allow this to happen in O(1).

Ok, but isn't joining two *singly linked lists* in O(1) one of the strengths of this simple data structure? Therefore I wonder -- **is there no operation on `forward_list` that splices/merges/joins an arbitrary number of elements in O(1)?**

The algorithm would be quite simple, of course. One would just need a name for the operation (pseudocode): (**Updated** by integrating Kerreks answer)

```
temp_this  =   pos.next;
temp_that  =  last.next;
  pos.next = first.next;
 last.next =  temp_this;
first.next =  temp_that;
```

The result is a bit different, because not `(first,last)` is moved, but `(first,last]`.

```
  this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7               x: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
          ^pos                            ^first      ^last
will become:
  this: 1 2 13 14 15 16 3 4 5 6 7   x: 11 12             17
          ^pos       ^last                ^first
```

I would think this is an as reasonable operation like the former one, that people might would like to do -- especially if it has the benefit of being O(1).

- **Am I overlooking a operation that is O(1) on many elements?**
- **Or is my assumption wrong that `(first,last]` might be useful as the moved range?**
- **Or is there an error in the O(1) algorithm?**

Comment: The details of your solution are a bit off, but the question is good. +1

Comment: *because not (first,last) is moved, but (first,last].* This exactly is the point, all standard algorithms work with that assumption, having such an exception would confuse people.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Isn't `splice_after` already violating the the standard assumptions, as all other algorithms work with [first,last)?

Comment: If there were a `before_end` iterator, then it could indeed be done.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Indeed. See how confusing this is? and how confusing would it be to have yet another deviating version. Standard containers are created for easy use, not for ultimate performance.

Comment: @plasma @Kerrek: Exacly. Yes, we must not break the expectations of the users that `forward_list` behaves differently of course. And yes, `scplice_after` already has a different name. But like I wanted to point out by "need a name" I'd like a completely different name for this operation. Only for `forward_lists` but O(1). Maybe `join` or something.

Comment: @towi: When you need such an operation to be O(1) then it is likely that you have other special requirements that make it worth to write your own linked list (after all, only a minority of people uses the splice functionality of standard lists). As said, the standard library is for easy use, not for performance or rich (fat) interfaces/functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm fails when you pass in `end()` as `last` because it will try to use the one-past-end node and relink it into the other list. It would be a strange exception to allow `end()` to be used in every algorithm except this one.

Also I think `first.next = &last;` needs to be `first.next = last.next;` because otherwise `last` will be in both lists.

Answer (score 7):

Let me first give a corrected version of your O(1) splicing algorithm, with an example:

```
temp_this  =   pos.next;
temp_that  =  last.next;

  pos.next = first.next;
 last.next =  temp_this;
first.next =  temp_that;
```

(A sanity check is to observe that every variable appears precisely twice, once set and once got.)

Example:

```
    pos.next                           last.next
    v                                  v
1 2 3 4 5 6 7        11 12 13 14 15 16 17 #    
  ^                     ^           ^     ^
  pos                   first       last  end             


becomes:

This:     1 2 13 14 15 16 3 4 5 6 7

That:   11 12             17
```

Now we see that in order to splice up to the end of `that` list, we need to provide an iterator to *one before the `end()`*. However, no such iterator exists in constant time. So basically the linear cost comes from discovering the final iterator, one way or another: Either you precompute it in O(n) time and use your algorithm, or you just splice one-by-one, also in linear time.

(Presumably you could implement your own singly-linked list that would store an additional iterator for `before_end`, which you'd have to keep updated during the relevant operations.)

Comment: We do *have* "one before the end". It is `last.next`, isn't it?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. The problem is that your proposed algorithm is only useful if one can sensibly obtain an iterator to the last element of the desired sequence, but that isn't possible in constant time in general. So the entire algorithm isn't deemed useful. In other words, how did you come by the `last` iterator in the first place?

Comment: @towi: he means one before `last`.

Comment: Yep. Got it from the other answers.

Comment: @Dani: No, not really. What I meant was that in general there isn't a constant-time operation that obtains a good end iterator. Coming to think of it, one could probably offer this algorithm as an alternative for situations in which you already obtained the iterator pair by other means. That sounds like something that would be situationally useful.

Comment: It's somewhat easy to maintain a `std::pair<std::forward_list<T>, iterator>`. You insert the first element as `it = list.insert_after(list.before_begin(), element);` and update that `it` anytime you insert after it (`it = list.insert_after(it, another_element);`). There are plenty of situations where that iterator will be 'fresh' and won't need to be manually recomputed.

Answer (score 4):

There was considerable debate within the LWG over this issue.  See [LWG 897](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#897) for some of the documentation of this issue.